How to use `sendAndConfirmTransaction` with `VersionedTransaction`
What is the recommended way to use sendAndConfirmTransaction with VersionedTransaction? Currently it only supports Transaction, but not VersionedTransaction.
I found this related example in the docs:
// send and confirm the transaction
// (NOTE: There is NOT an array of Signers here; see the note below...)
const txid = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transactionV0);


NOTE: When sending a VersionedTransaction to the cluster, it must be signed BEFORE calling the sendAndConfirmTransaction method. If you pass an array of Signer (like with legacy transactions) the method will trigger an error!

but in the current version of the library there isn't a signature of this function that has 2 parameters.
If that isn't possible what would be the easiest way to achieve the same behavior?

You can achieve the same behavior by using sendTransaction and then confirmTransaction
For example:
const transactionSignature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [
  signer_keypair,
]);

const { lastValidBlockHeight, blockhash } =
  await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

await connection.confirmTransaction(
  {
    blockhash: blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: transactionSignature,
  },
  "confirmed",
);

